# What does this infinite sum converge to?: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^k} = \frac1{1^k} + \frac1{2^k} + \frac1{3^k} + ...$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^k} = \dfrac{1}{1^k} + \dfrac{1}{2^k} + \dfrac{1}{3^k} + \dfrac{1}{4^k} + \dfrac{1}{5^k} +  ...$$

I've found that:

when $k=1$, it diverge to infinity

when $k=2$, it converge to $\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$

when $k=4$, it converge to $\dfrac{\pi^4}{90}$

when $k=6$, it converge to $\dfrac{\pi^6}{945}$

when $k=8$, it converge to $\dfrac{\pi^8}{9450}$

when $k=10$, it converge to $\dfrac{\pi^{10}}{93555}$

when $k=12$, it converge to $\dfrac{691 \pi^{12}}{638512875}$

When $k$ tends to infinity, it seems to tend to $1$.

Though I didn't found anything for the cases $k=3$, $k=5$, $k=7$, $k=9$, $k=11$, etc...

**I would like a formula that gives $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^k}$ according to $k$.**

The formula needs to be as simple as possible.

Is the formula simpler when written in terms of $\pi$, $\eta = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ or $\tau = 2 \pi$ ?

Comment: There is no nice closed form known when $k$ is odd.

Comment: fonction zeta !

Comment: @AndréNicolas There is too a nice closed form! It's $\zeta (2k+1)$.

Comment: That is a name, not a closed form in the usual sense. That is similar to other situations. If we admit elliptic functions, certain integrals that did not have a closed form do. Similar considerations apply to many special functions.

Comment: For bonus points: For what values of $k$ does the sum equal zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you like the following formula for the [Riemann zeta function](http://uk.arxiv.org/pdf/math/9812143v1). It is generalising the well-known formula for $\zeta(2n)$ in terms of Bernoulli numbers and powers of $\pi$ you have listed.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [Riemann Zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_Zeta_function).  There's simplified forms for even integers, but odd ones are much nastier.

Comment: Are they nasty ? Some are nice - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apéry's_constant.